# Collapse a TextBox vertically only - or get the actual height if it were hidden

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Consider the following simplified control code:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <TextBlock Text="xxx" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
  </TextBlock>

  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
  </TextBlock>

  <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
  </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

I conditionally (here: Value==0) hide the `TextBox`, so that `Value` is shown in the subjacent `TextBlock`. It works, but if I use `Collapsed`, the height of the control changes what I want to avoid. If I use `Hidden`, the width of the hidden `TextBox` pushes the Grids column 1.

What I want is to collapse the `TextBox` only in vertical direction, so that its height keeps the height of the control constant. Setting the height on the control to a fixed value feels bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following DataTrigger (Set the Width to 0).

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="0">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
 </DataTrigger>
```